# Integrating security to Spring MVC application (applicationContext Issue)

Tags: xml, spring, spring-security

I have build the Spring MVC application and got it to an advanced level.

Now my task is to integrate Spring Security to it. And I am now following [this tutorial](http://heraclitusonsoftware.wordpress.com/software-development/spring/simple-web-application-with-spring-security-part-1/) for spring security. Now the problem is that in my MVC application there is already a applicationContext.xml which is the parent application context definition for the MVC application.

As mention in tutorial for security, should I have to add a new application context xml file for security? which contain the code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-2.0.4.xsd">

    <global-method-security secured-annotations="disabled">
    </global-method-security>

    <http auto-config="true">
        <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="ROLE_USER" />
    </http>

    <authentication-provider>
        <user-service id="userDetailsService">
            <user name="username" password="password" authorities="ROLE_USER, ROLE_ADMIN" />
            <user name="test" password="test" authorities="ROLE_USER" />
        </user-service>
    </authentication-provider>
</beans:beans>
```

Thanks in advance.

P.S. / EDIT: Or should I just copy it to my original/existing applicationContext.xml file of my MVC application?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no problem or conflict with your other context. 
You could write the security configuration into context/applicationContext-security.xml for example and then just load all your context files from the web.xml.

```
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>classpath*:context/applicationContext*.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>
```

Comment: Thank a lot man. I have another question that here is a taglib in my MVC application's web.xml. Any idea what is this for?

Comment: 1) What taglib are you talking about?
2) As Ralph pointed, this tutorial is out-of-date, you should use one using Spring 3.0.

Answer (score 1):

It is best practice to have seperate spring configruation files for normal bean configuration and an other one for the security.

But the name does not matter!
You can name one for example `applicationContext.xml` and then other one `applicationContext-security.xml`

BTW: The Tutorial is a Spring 2 tutorial, you should have a look at a Tutorial that use Spring 3.0 and Spring Security 3.0! -- Spring Security 3.0 differs a lot from Spring Security 2.0!

Comment: Is this mean spring 2 in not compatible with spring security 3? What if I use Spring 2.0.4 instead of v 3.0?

Comment: @AbdulAziz: This is not a real question right, you already know the answer.

Comment: I am sorry. I got your point. This is because I have very limited time to complete the task and I am worry about it. Thank you